# How to break long axes labels in plotly chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, plotly, axis-labels

I am using plotly.js for my chart. I have dynamic labels for the y-axis. It is showing the full text in a single line while I need to break/wrap the label text in multiple lines. How to do this?

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with my notebook. What I did was pretty simple. While defining the `pd.DataFrame` I used `br`, which is an HTML line break tag, in the long texts to break them.

This is the output:
[image: this is the output]

For Ex -

```
concerns = pd.DataFrame({'Concerns':['Health and economic<br> impact on the<br> country', 
                         'A member of my<br> family might contract<br> COVID-19',
                         'Cost-cutting measures<br> that might impact<br> my compensation'],
                         'Percentage':[72, 61, 40]
                    })
```